# There is a nondiagonal matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $ I_{3} +A+A^2=O_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

There is a nondiagonal matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $ I_{3} +A+A^2=O_3$?

This question is related to this question [. There exists a nondiagonal matrix $A\in \mathcal {M}_n (\mathbb{R}) $ s.t. $A^{k+1}=I_n $ and $I_n-A $ invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615996/there-exists-a-nondiagonal-matrix-a-in-mathcal-m-n-mathbbr-s-t-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such real $3 \times 3$ matrix (diagonal or otherwise).  In particular, we note that every $3 \times 3$ matrix with real entries has a real eigenvalue, but if $v$ is an eigenvector associated with real eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$
(I + A + A^2)v = (1 + \lambda + \lambda^2)v \neq 0
$$